# Own digital clock with data und time. efficiently

Tags: android, handler, clock

Yesterday I programmed an own digital clock. I used the google blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html for help.

The following code is the resulat.

My question. Is it a efficient way, to update the handle by SystemClock.uptimeMillis()? I thought it would be better to habe something like a listener for change on time.

Second question. Is it effienc for the processor to use DateFormat.getTimeInstance() command to get the time? I use it because I don't know how to calculate the actual time from System.currentTimeMillis().

```
public class TextClock extends Activity {

    private TextView mTimeLabel;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mTimeLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeLabel);
    }

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   String currentTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                   String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
                   mTimeLabel.setText(currentDateString + "\n" + currentTimeString);

                   mHandler.postAtTime(this, (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 1000));
               }
            };

        @Override
            protected void onStart()
            {
                    super.onPause();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause()
            {
                    super.onPause();
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            }
}
```

Thank you for your comments.

Felix

Comment: this code works fine. for everybody who needs a simple calender & clock.

Comment: for everybody who is interested in a more simple clock can have a look here: http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.html (analog clock, digital clock)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind this saying: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil" In other words, if it ain't broke, don't fix it. When you are writing a clock application, small performance optimizations are unlikely to make a big difference to the user experience.

1. I don't see a problem with using `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` the way you are using it. Listeners are generally for events that happen irregularly, rather than routine (time-based) events.
2. It would probably be very, very, very slightly faster to manually parse the time from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, because there would be less function calls involved and less memory allocation (both of which have some overhead, especially in Java), however the savings would be tiny.